# has_many relationship reloading parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, activerecord

I have has_many relationship like this:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base 
    has_many :event_rows
    ...
end
class EventRow < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :event
    ...
end
```

When i run the snippet below, it show me 36 queries:

```
@events = Event.where("date = ?", @date).all
@events.each do |e|
    first = e.event_rows.first
    first.event
end
```

When i run this snippet, i get only 19 queries

```
@events = Event.where("date = ?", @date).all
@events.each do |e|
    first = e.event_rows.first
    first.event = e # forcing the parent
    first.event
end
```

Am i doing something wrong, or rails runs a query everytime an EventRow asks for its Event?

In response to comments: queries are not marked as CACHED:

```
SQL (0.7ms)[0m  SELECT "event_rows"."id" AS t0_r0, "event_rows"."event_id" ... WHERE "event_rows"."event_id" = 1 LIMIT 1
Event Load (0.6ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1[0m
SQL (3.2ms)[0m  SELECT "event_rows"."id" AS t0_r0, "event_rows"."event_id" ... WHERE "event_rows"."event_id" = 2 LIMIT 1
Event Load (0.5ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."id" = 2 LIMIT 1[0m
```

Comment: I guess most of those 36 queries are marked as cached in log, don't they?

Comment: I tried it now and they're not marked as cached.

Comment: Ah, this is in development? Model caching disabled by default in development so that may be the reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled across the answer for question.

It seems you can use the [inverse_of](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many#972-Undocumented-inverse-of-option) option to keep the same instance:

> Without :inverse_of m and f.man would be different instances of the same object (f.man being pulled from the database again). With these new :inverse_of options m and f.man are the same in memory instance.

Comment: It's difficult for me to understand why this would not be a default behaviour, but it seems to me that not only is it potentially very inefficient to miss out inverse_of, you could also get some nasty errors in your code without it.

Comment: Experienced rails developers got used to it, and avoid errors instinctively moving code to the parent or child class depending or whether the error is less likely to happen. Since i'm a beginner i was not used to it. I think they should make inverse_of the default behavior as soon as possible, not because of performance, but because all the beginners assume child.parent is the same instance parent was when they called parent.children.first.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with Michael Szyndel, model caching might be disabled in development, also i believe you would like to update your code as follow,

```
@events = Event.includes(:event_rows).where(date: @date)
@events.each do |e|
    # your code
end
```

I don't think you need `all`, what important here is includes which will do eager loading of event_rows.

Hope it would help..

Comment: The code i'm posting here is not the real code, it's just the simplest way i found to reproduce the bug. I'm already using includes(:event_rows). In the real code i'm not calling .first, i have   formulas and they happen to call event_row.event, which i found out to be running a query, since the event_rows were already included i'd assume event_row.event should already be populated. Anyway i created a workaround in my code. Just wanted to know if this is the default rails behavior. It could be 'smarter' and keep event_row.event populated.